# How can I read from stdin instead of the command line?

Tags: file-io, command-line-arguments, stdin

```
    FILE * file;
    file = fopen(argv[2] , "r");

    float val;

    if (file) {
        while (fscanf(file, "%s", str)!=EOF){
            val = atof(str);
            root = insert(root, val);
        }
            fclose(file);
        }else{
         exit(1);
        }
```

That is a section of the code I have right now. Im trying to change it so that it will read from stdin instead of from the command line. For example running the program would be "./a.out x < file.txt" instead of "./a.out x file.txt".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `fopen()` to open a file, use the `fdopen()` call to obtain a `FILE *` that sits on top of the file descriptor for standard input.  That's file descriptor 0, or you can use the literal `STDIN_FILENO` from the `unistd.h` header if you want to make your program easier for someone to read.  It will look like this:

```
file = fdopen(STDIN_FILENO, "r");
```

The rest of your program stays the same.